# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CalcTestNS'

Tags: python.net

I am trying to read a DLL file  using pythonnet library. The DLL file was generated using .NET framework 5.0 using the simple code below.

```
using System;

namespace CalcProcess
{
    public class Calculate
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        public int Sub(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to read object using the library as seen in the code below:

```
import sys

import clr

assembly_path = r"C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\CalcProcess\bin\Debug\net5.0"
sys.path.append(assembly_path)

#calling the dll file in the dll folder below
clr.AddReference("dll/CalcProcess")
from CalcProcess import Calculate

obj = Calculate()

print(obj.Add(1,2))
```

The line of code below gives the error in the topic below

```
from CalcProcess import calculate
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Where is CalcTestNS from?  How is your project organized?

Comment: I updated the question again to give  more context can you read through again please

Comment: I'm not familiar with this; but from a sample https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/demo/DynamicGrid.py,   could it be ```clr.AddReference(r"dll\CalcProcess")``` or even ```clr.AddReference(r"CalcProcess.dll")```?  Sorry..